# SWFObject like setup for Unity

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Is there a SWFObject type setup for embedding Unity content and having a fallback HTML content (with a link to install the plugin)?

The JS included with Unity only allows for a button they've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the official guide](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Detecting%20the%20Unity%20Web%20Player%20using%20browser%20scripting.html)

Basically, for non-IE browsers, you check that the plugin's installed using javascript, and for IE, you use VisualBasic scripting. Their code isn't terribly pretty (all those `document.write` calls - ugh!) but it's robust.

You can always take their code, clean it up and wrap it in a nicer package. I know I did (but for a client, so I can't give you the code - sorry)